# phpdocx Error while trying to open a template

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, mamp, phpdocx

I have downloaded phpdocx and I am testing my code on my local environment. I can successfully create a document from scratch with the following code:

```
$docx = new \Phpdocx\Create\CreateDocx();

$docx->addText('This is a test');
$docx->embedHTML('<p style="font-size: 30px;">New paragraph</p>');
$docx->createDocx(public_path() . '/output.docx');
```

However, I am needing to create a document from a template. Everytime I do so though I get the following error message:

> Error while trying to open the (base) template as a zip file

Here is my code:

```
$docx = new \Phpdocx\Create\CreateDocxFromTemplate(public_path() . '/Example Template.docx');

$variables = [
    '1' => 'John',
    '2' => 'Allen',
];

$docx->replaceVariableByText($variables);
$docx->createDocx(public_path() . '/output.docx');
```

Also, I am attaching a screenshot with more error details below:

[image]

Comment: Can you try removing white space in name and use `_` instead in file name like `Exmple_template.docx`

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and unfortunately I am still receiving the same error message.

Comment: do you know about config file of package you've used phpdocx?

Comment: also your application have read/write access?

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Yes, the file and folder both have read/write access.

Comment: Please check this [documentation](https://www.phpdocx.com/en/forum/default/topic/762)

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik tried that as well and still no luck.